# Postgres DB migration fails with "violates not-null constraint"

Tags: python, database, postgresql, migration

I am trying to upgrade Netbox (https://github.com/digitalocean/netbox) from older version (2.3.7) to newer one (2.4.3) by using upgrade script which include the step manage.py migrate.
And on this step it fails with error:

```html
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/opt/netbox/netbox$ python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, circuits, contenttypes, dcim, extras, ipam, secrets, sessions, taggit, tenancy, users, virtualization
Running migrations:
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, auth, 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length, 2018-09-04 17:29:15.531382+00).
```

The postgres DB has already been filled. 
If I run on the empty DB upgrade works normally.
But as a newbie I don't have an idea how to tshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this occurs when you are running Postgres 9.x and the data you imported came from Postgres 10.